# Sorting Data on Form in Access 2010 by VBA

Tags: vba, forms, sorting, ms-access

I have the following setup:

Table "Mitarbeiter" (Users) with fields: "UNummer" / "Sortierung" /....

Table "Mo01" (a sheet for every month) with fields: "UNummer" / "01" / "02" / ....

The Field UNummer in Table Mo01 is a combination field that gets Mitarbeiter.UNummer and saves it as text

I call a Form "Monatsblatt" that is based on the table Mo01.

In that Form I have a Field "fldSort" that is calling "Sortierung" from table "Mitarbeiter". The Data in that field is based on "=DomWert("Sortierung";"Mitarbeiter";"UNummer = '" & [ID] & "'")"

This works and looks like this:
[image: Image of the Form]

I am trying to sort the form by that "fldSort" in Form "Monatsblatt" by using this code:

```
Form_Monatsblatt.OrderBy = "fldSort"
Form_Monatsblatt.OrderByOn = True
```

When I start the form with that code running, Access asks for parameters:
[image: Access asking for Parameter]

I tried a lot of different ways of writing the code, referencing to the field in different ways. I do NOT want to base the form on anything other then the table.

Answer (score 2):

Why not ask the wide world watch "Why Access asking me for Parameter"? That would have brought you to the clue I think. `Debug.Print` or  `MsgBox` your `.OrderBy` and you see it's "fldSort", not a valid sort. Access is assuming you want to use a parameter called `fldSort`, but you want the string in the variable `fldSort`, but it's not recognized, because of the double quotes surrounding it. Everything between 2 double quotes is interpreted as a string, even it's a var name.

Delete the quotes and everything will work fine (if your sort string is sufficent)!

```
 Form_Monatsblatt.OrderBy = fldSort
```

[Update]
Late, but now I see the clue. You added a calculated field to the form, but you can't sort or filter them.
Instead of appending this field to the table, create a query and add it there, then you bind the form to the query and add the field to the form. Now you can filter and sort as you like!
The query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT *,
    Dlookup("Sortierung","Mitarbeiter","UNummer = '" & [ID] & "'") AS ldSort
FROM Mo01;
```

Or with a join:

```sql
SELECT 
  Mo01.*, 
  Mitarbeiter.Sortierung AS fldSort
FROM 
  Mo01 
LEFT JOIN 
  Mitarbeiter 
ON 
  Mo01.ID = Mitarbeiter.UNummer;
```

Now you can use

```vb
Form_Monatsblatt.OrderBy = "fldSort"
Form_Monatsblatt.OrderByOn = True
```

because you have a bound control called `fldSort`.

[/Update]

Comment: Good Answer. Helps partially. Unfortunately the sorting does not work at all that way. Basically i want to sort the Table in a customized way by a connected field from another table without using anything else then tables. Anyone got an idea how to do that?

Comment: What is value of `fldSort`? I think its not a valid sort string.

Comment: the value is a number (double). What i'm trying to do at the moment is to instead add a field to the tables and fill it in the form with an update query and then to sort the table with the now entered value. i guess that will actually work. however, now i have some trouble with the update query.

Comment: It has to be the name of the field you want to sort.

Comment: well. it finally works by inserting the field into the table and put it right in front. then it will sort find. a bit of a hammer-solution, but it works. thanks anyway.

Comment: Not a good solution, look at my updated answer and create a query. I am not sure about the field ID. Is it the name of the control bound to UNummer? Then replace ID with UNummer in Code.